# Iterate over a specific column in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over the second column (first index) in a dictionary similar to:

```
dict    =   {
"Me": [("Blue", 37, 1,  2, "up", "left")],
"You": [("Green",  03, 3, 4, "up", "right"),
    ("Red", 29, 5, 6, "down", "right"),
    ("Yellow", 35, 7,  8, "straight", "down")],
"Them": [("Black", 08, 9, 10, "up", "up"),
    }
```

and retrun the largest value.  What I have is:

```
    for c in dict[1:2]:

    x = 0

    if c > x:

        x = c

return x
```

I'm getting an unhashable type error.  I know it has something to do with how the code iterates over the dictionary but I'm stuck on how to fix it.  Language is Python.  What is wrong here?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dict`s are not sequences, you cannot index them, and you certainly cannot slice them. And for that matter, they do not have "columns."

Answer (score 1):

First, STOP using reserved names (like dict) for your variables

Second, by writing mydict[1:2] you request the value from dictionary that refers to the element with the key 1:2, which is the slice operator.
   Now the slice operator can't be a key in a dictionary (there isn't a hash function that takes the operator and returns a numeric value which is used as index in the values array).
   So, you should use the slice operator on the list of keys and list of values, or on the list of items - lists which have an order and it makes sense to have slices on them (the dictionary is not guaranteed to have the same order after it's changed)

Third, why do you set the x to 0 in every iteration in the for loop?

And fourth, you could do this:

```
for value in mydict.values():
    (a, b, c, d, e, f) = value[0]
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`1:2` is a slice object, which is unhashable, what you want instead is something like this:

```
max(d[1] for l in dict.values() for d in l)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using dict.iteritems() to iterate over key-value pairs?

ex:

```
for key, val in dic.iteritems():
    print "Key: " + str(key) + "\t Value:" + str(val)
```